# Web.config WordPress rewrite rules next to Magento

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, magento, iis, http-code-500

I've installed Magento on IIS in folder: `E:\mydomain\wwwroot` (I already have it all running correctly).

I have no deeper folder `magento`, I placed all files directly in the `wwwroot` folder, so:

```
wwwroot\app
wwwroot\downloader
wwwroot\errors
wwwroot\includes
etc...
```

**UPDATE**: since I'm on IIS my `.htaccess` is ignored completely and my `web.config` rules are used instead. Here's my web.config in folder `e:\mydomain\wwwroot`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Magento SEO: remove index.php from URL">
          <match url="^(?!index.php)([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(media|skin|js)/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Next, I wanted to install WordPress.
I unzipped all files in folder `e:\mydomain\wwwroot\wordpress`

Browsed to www.mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php, where I configured everything for my database.
Everything was installed correctly.

I then navigate to http://www.mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-login.php where I type my credentials. I seem to be logged in and am redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-admin/
But there I receive an empty page.
I enabled detailed error message in IIS following this article: http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis
I also checkec with Fiddler and see that I receive a 500 error:

GET /wordpress/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mydomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://www.mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-login.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Cookie: wordpress_fabec4083cf12d8de89c98e8aef4b7e3=floran%7C1381236774%7C2d8edb4fc6618f290fadb49b035cad31; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_fabec4083cf12d8de89c98e8aef4b7e3=floran%7C1381236774%7Cbf822163926b8b8df16d0f1fefb6e02e

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.14
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2013 12:56:03 GMT
Content-Length: 0

My WordPress web.config in folder `e:\mydomain\wwwroot\wordpress` contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also want my WordPress articles to be available on `www.mydomain.com/blog` instead of `www.mydomain.com/wordpress`

Ofcourse my admin links for Magento and Wordpress should also work.

How can I configure my web.config files to achieve the above?

Comment: What does the `.htaccess` file look like within the WordPress folder?

Comment: @Anagio: Hmm...I have no .htaccess file at all in folder \wwwroot\wordpress what should it contain?

Comment: I just realized you're on IIS not Apache. Check the IIS info on this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: @Anagio: I checked out your linkk. It contains example rewrite rules when rewriting Wordpress links. I don't know how to merge those rules with my current web.config rewrite rules (see my updated post). Thanks!

Comment: i'm not very familiar with IIS, if it were Apache2 I could be more help. All I can suggest is try Googling WordPress rewrite permalinks and IIS

Comment: It's unclear as to how Magento is related to WordPress in this question, and if that's working correctly. Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish? Please use formatting for URLs and error messages (like I added previously, but were removed by your edits) so that the question can be read more easily too.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth turning on detailed error messages in IIS so you can find out what's causing that 500 error. By default IIS will not show detailed errors unless you're requesting the page from localhost.

Comment: see my updated post. I enabled detailed errors, but still receive an empty page...any suggestions?

Comment: Yep, check the event logs. Most of the time they are pretty cryptic. but you might get lucky and find another clue.

Comment: I enabled logging in IIS and a new log is created when I request /wordpress/index.php, however, the log file is empty. Now what?

Comment: Not the IIS log files... the Windows Event Log.  Start > search for Event Viewer, open it, go to Windows Logs > Application. That's all I can offer.